# Title of Collapsing toolbar is not changing when setting dynamically?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have used viewpager for showing the data of per month. and I want to change the title of collapsing toolbar accroding to change in viewpager's page.
Collapsing toolbar title only changes when scrolling up the toolbar.
[image]

my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_history_view_pager_height" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_history_collapsing_toolbar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_flexible_space"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_history_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_history_margin_left"
            android:text="@string/activity_history_year"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_history_text_size" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_history_margin_bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_history_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_history_margin_right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_leftBackArrow"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/previous_arrow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_rightBackArrow"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_history_arrow_size"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/next_arrow" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In Activity

```
    /**
     * Lists History of the Tasks and it's status on the basis of Date
     */
    public class HistoryActivity extends BaseActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        @InjectView(R.id.toolbar_flexible_space)
        Toolbar toolbar;

        @InjectView(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)
        CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbar;

        @InjectView(R.id.view_pager)
        ViewPager viewPager;

        @InjectView(R.id.txt_year)
        TextView txtYear;
        int viewPagerSize = 0;

        ArrayList<String> taskAddedMonths;

        @OnClick({R.id.img_leftBackArrow, R.id.img_rightBackArrow})
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.img_rightBackArrow:
                    moveForward();
                    break;
                case R.id.img_leftBackArrow:
                    moveBackWard();
                    break;

            }

        }

        /**
         * move view pager page as accroding to clicking on backword arrow.
         */
        private void moveBackWard() {
            int currentPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if (currentPosition > 0) {
                int nextPosition = currentPosition - 1;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPosition);
                mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(getCollapsingToolbarTitle(taskAddedMonths.get(nextPosition)));
            }
        }

        /**
         * move view pager page as according to clicking on forward arrow.
         */
        private void moveForward() {
            int currentPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

            if (currentPosition < viewPagerSize-1) {
                int nextPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                if (viewPagerSize == 1) {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition + 1);
                    mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(getCollapsingToolbarTitle(taskAddedMonths.get(nextPosition)));
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            taskAddedMonths = DatabaseManager.getInstance(HistoryActivity.this).getAllMonths();
            viewPagerSize = taskAddedMonths.size();

            mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(getCollapsingToolbarTitle(taskAddedMonths.get(0)));
            mCollapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_backarrow));

            viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(HistoryActivity.this, DatabaseManager.getInstance(HistoryActivity.this).getAllMonths()));
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public int getLayoutId() {
            return R.layout.activity_history;
        }

        @Override
        public Toolbar getToolbar() {
            return toolbar;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_history, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * get the name of month with concatenating History as like this{May History};
         *
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private String getCollapsingToolbarTitle(String month) {
            return month + " " + "History";
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
/******************* what i have done*******************/
            //change the title of collapsing toolbar accroding to change in page of viewpager
            mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(getCollapsingToolbarTitle(taskAddedMonths.get(position)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am too facing same problem. AFAIK till now you can't set title of collapsing toolbar dynamically you can set it statically only. So if you have any solution do post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175808&can=1) that should be fixed in the `v22.2.1` release of the design library.